# Run Java applications with JDK on OS X

Tags: macos, java, jdk

Apple in the latest releases of OS X removed Java from default installation so for my needs I installed JDK from Oracle's website.

```
~ java -version                                                                                                                                     
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

It works fine in Terminal and for for my apps but when I launch any app for mac written in Java I get typical "To open X you need to install Java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to install one now?" message.

Is there a way to tell OS X to launch Java apps with java I installed without installing another one? I'm trying to run IntelliJ IDEA 12.